# Attribute name is a reserved keyword in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting the error that the column name is a reserved keyword when reading values from DynamoDB. I am trying to read the value of a column named 'Status'.

My script:

```
<script>
    AWS.config.update({
      region: "us-west-2",
      endpoint: 'https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      accessKeyId: "Fakeaccesskey",
      secretAccessKey: "Fakesecretkey"
    });

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    function readItembedonestatus() {
        var table = "TA_Latest_Log";
        var GWID = "BB00000001";
        var ID = "AA00000013";

        var params = {
            TableName: table,
            Key:{
                "GWID": GWID,
                "ID": ID
            },
               "ProjectionExpression": "#node_status"
               "ExpressionAttributeNames": "#node_status": "Status"
        };
        docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                document.getElementById('bedonestatus').innerHTML = "Unable to read item: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('bedonestatus').innerHTML = data.Item.#node_status + "&deg;";

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

I added the ExpressionAttributeNames, however, I am not able to get it to work. The script above returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    AWS.config.update({
      region: "us-west-2",
      endpoint: 'https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      accessKeyId: "Fakeaccesskey",
      secretAccessKey: "Fakesecretkey"
    });

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    function readItembedonestatus() {
        var table = "TA_Latest_Log";
        var GWID = "BB00000001";
        var ID = "AA00000013";

        var params = {
            TableName: table,
            Key:{
                "GWID": GWID,
                "ID": ID
            },
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#node_status":"Status"},
            ProjectionExpression: "#node_status"
        };
        docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                document.getElementById('bedonestatus').innerHTML = "Unable to read item: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('bedonestatus').innerHTML = data.Item.#node_status + "&deg;";

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

ExpressionAttributeNames has to be a map. And you are missing a comma in your params list..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still the same. It's not returning anything

Comment: @ Stu posting it as a new reply because this is not allowing proper formatting in the comments.

Comment: Most likely there is no matching item or the item does not have an attribute named Status. I can't help you without an error message or a working query you want to edit.

Comment: Status is there and a similar working query is given below I posted. It just does not have the reserved keyword.

Comment: Ok, I see. Can you post the whole item (the values) you are trying to find?

Comment: And the table schema (the attribute names)

Comment: The values and attribute names I am reading successfully are Hum (humidity) and BatV (battery voltage). It's only Status I can't seem to figure out. Hum works the same way as the BatV script I posted.

Comment: Hum and BatV are numbers and Status is text

Comment: A ProjectionExpression, works AFTER the query. So the only reason it wouldn&#39;t be working is if the item does not have an attribute named Status. Check your item for that attribute.

Comment: If you remove the ProjectionExpression Param you will see the whole item. Post that item.

Answer (score 0):

The following query works but that's because it does not have a reserved keyword (BatV).

```
<script>
    AWS.config.update({
      region: "us-west-2",
      endpoint: 'https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      accessKeyId: "Fakeaccesskey",
      secretAccessKey: "Fakesecretkey"
    });

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    function readItemkitchenbat() {
        var table = "TA_Latest_Log";
        var GWID = "BB00000001";
        var ID = "AA00000029";

        var params = {
            TableName: table,
            Key:{
                "GWID": GWID,
                "ID": ID
            },
               "ProjectionExpression": "BatV"
        };
        docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                document.getElementById('kitchenbat').innerHTML = "Unable to read item: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('kitchenbat').innerHTML = data.Item.BatV + "V";
                
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

This is Amazon's documentation on reserved keywords: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html